# Making PySimpleGUI's SystemTray.notify non_blocking/ asynchronous

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

I'm working on a notification client for Windows 10 clients.

As of now I am using PySimpleGUI's SystemTray.notify class method to push the actual notification. The notification is meant to stay until the user has actively clicked it. Unfortunately SystemTray.notify is not non blocking and the code will stop until the user has clicked the notification. This is a problem because this doesnt allow the user to get multiple or newer  notifications.

I already tried the following:

- using PySimpleGUI's popups instead - basically worked, but couldn't get the right "look and feel" due to limited styling possibilities
- using PySimpleGUI's windows instead - couldn't get those non blocking while staying open
- using concurrent.futures (ThreadPoolExecuter) to execute the notification function "outside of the loop" - actually worked and made the notification non blocking but stopped working after displaying the first notification

Maybe the answer is somewhere in the things I already tried but I couldn't just get it right with my limited knowlegde or I missed something in the documentation. (GUI and asynchronism are completely new to me) Or maybe there is an complete different approach to this.

If you need a part of my code feel free to ask.

Edit:

```
def create_popup(n):
    dx, dy = sg.SYSTEM_TRAY_WIN_MARGINS
    screen_res_x, screen_res_y = sg.Window.get_screen_size()
    layout = [[sg.Text(myresult[2])],
        [sg.Text(myresult[3])],
        [sg.Button('Ok')]]
    window = sg.Window("Title", layout, keep_on_top=True, no_titlebar=True, grab_anywhere=True, finalize=True)
    width, height = window.size
    window.move(screen_res_x-width-dx, screen_res_y-height-dy)
    return window

query() # Gets last notification from mysql connector
last_notification=myresult[0]

while True:  # My event loop
        menu_item = tray.read(timeout=10000)
        if menu_item == 'Exit':
            break
        elif menu_item == 'Open':
            sgt.popup('For later use')
        query() # Gets last notification from mysql connector
        notification_now=myresult[0]
        if notification_now>last_notification:
            popup = create_popup(randint(1, 100))
            tray.read(timeout=100)
            last_notification=notification_now
        win, event, values = sg.read_all_windows(timeout=10000)
        if  event == 'Ok':
            popup.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple example, not everything same as method `notify` of `sg.SystemTray`.
I do it by multi-window solution.

```py
from random import randint
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def create_popup(n):
    dx, dy = sg.SYSTEM_TRAY_WIN_MARGINS
    screen_res_x, screen_res_y = sg.Window.get_screen_size()
    layout = [[sg.Text(f'You have {n} messages !', size=(25, 1), key='-MESSAGE-')]]
    window = sg.Window("Title", layout, keep_on_top=True, no_titlebar=True, grab_anywhere=True, finalize=True)
    width, height = window.size
    window.move(screen_res_x-width-dx, screen_res_y-height-dy)
    return window

message = 'Hello World'
menu_def = ['UNUSED', ['Popup', 'Update', 'Exit']]
tray = sg.SystemTray(menu=menu_def, data_base64=sg.DEFAULT_BASE64_ICON)

popup, running, count = None, False, 0

while True:

    win, event, values = sg.read_all_windows(timeout=3000)

    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    elif event == 'Popup' and not running:
        running = True
        popup = create_popup(randint(1, 100))
    elif event == 'Update' and running:
        popup['-MESSAGE-'].update(f'You have {randint(1, 100)} messages !')
    elif event == sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT and running:
        popup.close()
        popup, running = None, False

if popup:
    popup.close()
tray.close()
```

Update for any popup window closed by button `OK`

```py
from random import randint
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def popup():
    sg.Window('Title', [[sg.Text("Message")], [sg.Button("OK")]], location=(randint(0, 1600), randint(0, 700)) , finalize=True)

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Main Window")],
    [sg.Button("New Window"), sg.Button('Exit')],
]

window = sg.Window('Test Program', layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    win, event, values = sg.read_all_windows()
    if win == window:
        if event == "New Window":
            popup()
        elif event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
            break
    elif event in ("OK", sg.WINDOW_CLOSED):
        win.close()

for win in list(sg.Window._active_windows.keys()):
    win.close()
```

Comment: Hi Jason, first of all thanks for helping me two times in a row!

I couldn't get your code running but I was able to implement it into my code (changed it slightly because i wanted a  "Ok"  button in the popup) and it works pretty good, so thanks for that! However, I'm still having one problem and I'm not sure if there is a solution to this in your code: Lets say there are multiple popups open, how do I tell the code to close the popup I clicked Ok instead of closing the last recent one? I guess I have to implement some kind of an ID logic? Do you have an idea? Code  snippet in question edit

Comment: Check the `win` to tell the event `OK` come from which popup, then close the popup.

Comment: I'm not sure what "Check the `win` " means, can you please explain a bit further, or provide a code snippet?

Comment: Here the `win` means which window generated the event for statement `win, event, values = sg.read_all_windows(timeout=3000)`. For example, button OK with `key=f"OK {index}"`, you can check `if event.startswith("OK")`, then `win.close()`.

Comment: oh, index is not necessary for different window/popup, maybe just `elif event == 'OK': win.close()` if all buttons with same key `'OK'`.

Comment: Adding `elif event == 'OK': win.close()` didnt work: when closing one window the others will freeze. All windows have the same button `"OK"` 
Maybe I have to index the windows? (You can see my code in my question)

Comment: IMO, you must do something wrong, so update my post.